# What is this paper fan used by some student council president/senior member called?

Tags: tropes

In many anime, a student council president or senior member uses essentially a paper 'fan' to discipline others.  Kind of looks like a paper that has been folded up.

Is it really a fan of some sort or something different? Does it has a specific name (in Japanese)?

Answer (score 7):

That'd be a Harisen, a paper fan used extensively in manzai comedy by the *tsukkomi* to smack the *bokke*'s funny antics. I guess it just bleeded into anime for its comedic factor.